# Get URL Title from External URL without loading whole Website

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, url, textarea

I have a javascript code which shows all the urls in a textarea / textbox. I would like to show the web title of those urls. But I don't want to load the whole website (get_content) as it manipulates the other javascripts on my page. How can I show the title?

**My Code**

```
<script>
let result = $("#converted_url");
$("#textarea_input").on("input", function() {
  result.html("");
  var urlRegex = /(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?([-a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4})\b(?:\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  var found = [];
  $("#textarea_input").val().replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    let trimmedUrl = url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, "");
    if (found.includes(trimmedUrl)) {
      return;
    }
    found.push(trimmedUrl);
    var link = '<a target="_blank" href="' + url + '">' + TITLE + '</a>';
    result.append(link);
  });
});
</script>
```

**Should output something like this:**

[image]

Comment: As @IceMetalPunk mentions below you have to load the html first and then parse out what you want and don't want - so just the title in your case.  If loading the pages "manipulates the Javascripts on my page" then you will need to change your javascript so it does not clash.  For example you might have functions in your javascript that have the same names as functions in the loaded page's javascript so adopt more unique names for yours - but this shouldn't be happening if you are using AJAX.

Comment: ohh ok. Well thank you very much for your time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: you can't. The title of a webpage is only stored in its HTML content, so without downloading that content, you can't get the title. I don't understand what you mean by "it manipulates the Javascripts on my page" -- if you make an AJAX call to the URL you want (assuming it's same-domain or has CORS enabled), you'll get back the raw source code as a string to parse as you wish, and it won't affect anything else on your page.

Comment: thank you very much for the explaination. Guess I have to change my code so it doesn't clash :/

Comment: Maybe, but you really haven't explained what's clashing in the first place. Getting the string content of a URL request shouldn't affect any of your page or other scripts in any way. What exactly is the issue you're experiencing? The more we know about the problem, the more we can help you find a solution.